# cpp static template-dimension pass-as-reference when leading dimension may be zero

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I have the following function.

```cpp
template<int m, int n>
void foo(float (&A)[m][n]){}

int main(){
    float x[3][4], y[0][4];
    
    foo<3,4>(x);
    //if(false){ foo<0,4>(y); } // POSITION 1
}
```

When I uncomment the line that includes`POSITION 1`, then the following error is thrown:

```
$ g++ minimum_example.cpp

.\minimum_example.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\minimum_example.cpp:10:13: error: no matching function for call to 'foo<0, 4>(float [0][4])'
   10 |     foo<0,4>(y);
      |     ~~~~~~~~^~~
.\minimum_example.cpp:3:6: note: candidate: 'template<int m, int n> void foo(float (&)[m][n])'
    3 | void foo(float (&A)[m][n]){}
      |      ^~~
.\minimum_example.cpp:3:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

$
```

The issue is that I cannot catch the exception `m==0` at compile time.
Preferably, I am interested in a solution that does not change the call syntax from the main() POV.

Comment: zero sized array is non-standard

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is as follows:

```cpp
template<int m, int n>
void foo(float A[m][n]){}

int main(){
    float x[3][4], y[0][4];
    
    foo<3,4>(x);
    //if(false){ foo<0,4>(y); } // POSITION 1
}
```

That is, you just replace `(&A)` with `A` in line 2.

Reasons are:

- Violation of standard is of no practical relevance in this matter because the code does in GCC and CLANG exactly what it is supposed to do.
- A reference cannot be passed explicitly because a reference to a NULL array cannot be generated (therefore the compilation error).
- The `(&A)` *can* be replaced with `A` because when $m>0$ the notation `A[m][n]` passes A as reference.

Comment: well, despite it doesn't pass a reference, you lose a dimension information, the dimention cannot be deduced, and [it does not really compile in clang even without flag](https://godbolt.org/z/zT95dKxhT).